# I am working on this code to update google contacts with google forms and spreadsheet linked to it

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, android-contacts, google-forms

I want this code to auto add contacts using trigger when form is submit but i get errors.
The code works properly with spreadsheet but I am not able get it work with forms.
I am kind of noob with coding.
So simple explanation would be helpful

Also contacts get add to "other" group in google contacts,is there any way to add them directly to "my contacts"?

```
function createHeaders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // Freezes the first row
  sheet.setFrozenRows(1);

  // Set the values we want for headers
  var values = [
    ["First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Phone Number", "Company", "Notes"]
  ];

  // Set the range of cells
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:F1");

  // Call the setValues method on range and pass in our values
  range.setValues(values);
}

function createContact() {
  var alreadyAdded = "Already added";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process

  // Fetch the range of cells A2:G3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 8)

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var firstName = row[0]
    var lastName = row[1]
    var emailAddress = row[2]
    var phone = row[3]
    var company = row[4]
    var notes = row[5]
    var addedAlready = row[6];

      if (addedAlready != alreadyAdded) {
      // Create contact in Google Contacts
      var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(firstName, lastName, emailAddress);

      // Add values to new contact
      contact.addCompany(company, "");
      contact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_PHONE, phone);
      contact.setNotes(notes);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue(alreadyAdded);
      }; 
    };
};
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting and on what line? How are you setting up your triggers?

Comment: Service error: ContactsApp: [Line 1, Column 384, element gd:givenName] Missing required text content (line 22, file "Code")....This is the error i recieve.

Comment: I am using on form submit trigger.

Comment: I got it working by linking the sheets .
But contacts get add to "other" group in google contacts,is there any way to add them directly to "my contacts"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error by passing one or more empty strings as arguments to the createContact() method:

```
var contact = ContactsApp.createContact("", "", "");
```

Check the values in your data array by logging them to see if you've got any empty strings there. You can wrap the code in a try block the prevent errors from stopping program execution. Any errors will be logged in a catch block

```
try {
var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(a, b, c);

}

catch(error) {

Logger.log(error);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. It works when I use it only for spreadsheet and updates the data. But I am not able to add it to form spreadsheet.

Comment: I tested everything in the sheet that was linked to form. 1) Make sure your form is properly linked to the sheet. Try creating another form and sheet 2) Be sure to run the function MANUALLY from the script editor at least once to grant all required permissions to your script. Your script will not run if you don't explicitly allow it to access your contacts.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to connect your Spreadsheet to Google Form. Check the [Connecting to Google Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#connecting_to_google_forms)

> Apps Script allows you to connect Google Forms with Google Sheets
>   through Forms and Spreadsheet services. This feature can automatically
>   create a Google Form based on data in a spreadsheet. Apps Script also
>   enables you to use triggers, such as onFormSubmit to perform a
>   specific action after a user responds to the form.

you might be referring to `onFormSubmit`.

Here's the [code demo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms) for your reference.